# Por favor: ¿Cómo redirigir a una portada alternativa en Wordpress si llegan con Internet Explorer?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirección

Hay una desconfiguración en la portada de mi web si se ve desde internet Explorer. Mientras los desarrolladores arreglan el problema (el módulo flex de la plantilla Newspaper8 de Wordpress), he creado una portada alternativa para redirigir a los que llegan en ese navegador a la otra portada, desarrollada con otros módulos.

La idea sería: si el usuario llega con IE, en lugar de https://www. dominio.com  que vaya a https://www. dominio.com/ie     Sólo afectaría a la portada. El resto se ve correctamente. He probado con plugins, incluyendo redirect, pero no funciona. redirige cualquier navegador. Gracias por la ayuda de antemano. Muchas gracias, de verdad.

Answer (score 0):

Buscando pude encontrar solo este script, una cosa interesante es que parece que este script esta para el Edge y no para el IE pero podria ser de tu utilidad modificandolo.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var detectarNavegador = window.navigator.userAgent;
var chrome = /Chrome/;
var firefox = /Firefox/;
var opera = /OPR/;
var edge = /Edge/;
var safari = /Safari/;
var navegador;
if(chrome.test(detectarNavegador) && !(opera.test(detectarNavegador)) && !(edge.test(detectarNavegador))){
    navegador = 'Google Chrome';
}else if(firefox.test(detectarNavegador)){
    navegador = 'Firefox Mozilla';
}else if(safari.test(detectarNavegador) && !(chrome.test(detectarNavegador))){
    navegador = 'Apple Safari';
}else if(opera.test(detectarNavegador)){
    navegador = 'Opera';
}else if(edge.test(detectarNavegador)){
    navegador = 'Microsoft Edge';
}else{
    navegador = 'un navegador desconocido';
}
alert('Detectado tu navegador con Expresión Regular.\nEstás usando: '+navegador);


if(detectarNavegador.indexOf('Chrome')!=-1 && detectarNavegador.indexOf('OPR')==-1 && detectarNavegador.indexOf('Edge')==-1){
    navegador = 'Google Chrome';
}else if(detectarNavegador.indexOf('Firefox')!=-1){
    navegador = 'Firefox Mozilla';
}else if(detectarNavegador.indexOf('Safari')!=-1 && detectarNavegador.indexOf('Chrome')==-1){
    navegador = 'Apple Safari';
}else if(detectarNavegador.indexOf('OPR')!=-1){
    navegador = 'Opera';
}else if(detectarNavegador.indexOf('Edge')!=-1){
    navegador = 'Microsoft Edge';
}else{
    navegador = 'un navegador Desconocido';
}
alert('Detectado tu navegador con "indexOf".\nEstás usando: '+navegador)
```